# "getaddrinfo" error when trying to establish an SSH connection using Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Using Paramiko I am trying to establish a connection with a server, but that connection is failing with the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ucatsScripts\cleanUcatsV2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ssh.connect(host,username,password)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.7.6-py2.7.egg\paramiko\client.py", line 278, in connect
    for (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) in socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed
```

Here is the code I am using

```
import paramiko
import cmd
import sys

# Connect to Server
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
    paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

success = ssh.connect('MASKED',username='MASKED',password='MASKED')
if (success != True):
    print "Connection Error"
    sys.exit()
else:
    print "Connection Established"
```

any ideas?

Comment: What's the format of your `hostname` argument to `ssh.connect`?  If you have a port tacked onto the end of the hostname, it needs to be passed as a separate argument instead.

Comment: Also, your `if (success != True):` block will be useless since `paramiko.SSHClient.connect` does not return a value.

Answer (score 10):

Just add the port after the host and you'll be set:

```
ssh.connect('MASKED', 22, username='MASKED',password='MASKED')
```

BTW, as robots.jpg said, the connect method doesn't return anything. Instead of returning values it triggers [exceptions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html).

Here is a more complete example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import paramiko, os, string, pprint, socket, traceback, sys

time_out = 20 # Number of seconds for timeout
port     = 22
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=2)
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

file = open( "file.txt", "r" )
# NOTE: The file contains:    
# host  user  current_password

array = []

for line in file:
  array = string.split(line.rstrip('\n'),)
#  pp.pprint(array)
  try:
    ssh.connect(array[0], port, array[1], array[2], timeout=time_out)
    print "Success!! -- Server: ", array[0], "   Us: ", array[1]
  except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
    print "Authentication problem   -- Server: ", array[0], "   User: ", array[1]
    continue
  except socket.error, e:
    print "Comunication problem    -- Server: ", array[0], "   User: ", array[1]
    continue
  ssh.close()

file.close()
```

The code needs some polish but it does the job.

Answer (score 3):

Be care to didn't have the username on your hostname

```
ssh.connect(hostname='user@example.com', port=22)
```

`user@example.com` isn't a hostname parameter that fit for the connection.

You should use:

```
ssh.connect(hostname='example.com', port=22, username='user')
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the hostname resolves to IP address? Try `ping that_hostname` on your machine to see.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes for DNS.
Go to Network Connections -> IPv4-> Advanced Settings -> DNS then check Append these DNS suffixes, and enter your machine dns.
This worked for me. Anyway this error comes from the Ethernet settings.
Good Luck !