# Socket error when connecting to remote machine with Python

Tags: python, unix, ssh, paramiko

I am using Python's paramiko package to connect to a remote Unix machine. I have written this code:

```
import paramiko
import sys
import os
import os.path
passwd = "XXX"
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect("173.15.13.28", "root", password=passwd)
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
x = stdout.readlines()
print x
for line in x:
   print line
ssh.close()
```

after executing I am getting this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
      ssh.connect("173.15.13.28", "root", password="--------")
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\paramiko\client.py", line 282, in connect
      for (family, socktype, proto, canonname, sockaddr) in socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port,socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
    gaierror: [Errno 10109] getaddrinfo failed
```

I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: You should probably change your password now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument of the [connect()](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.connect) method is the port number, which defaults to 22.  You are putting "root" there, which won't work.  Use the keyword argument `username="root"`.  That is, try this:

```
ssh.connect("173.15.13.28", username="root", password=passwd)
```

See also: [python paramiko, getaddrinfo error when trying to establish an SSH connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5301378/python-paramiko-getaddrinfo-error-when-trying-to-establish-an-ssh-connection)